# How to change blacks to 100% black in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, text, black

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days and I just can't seem to figure it out, hopefully someone can help!

I did a job where I edited a brochure, the original design files were destroyed and all that was left were the final PDFS. I made the edits on PSD, I deleted the old text and placed a new text layer on top. I changed some of the text but most of it stayed as it was before. I saved the files as PDFS and sent them to the printer.

The printer asked me to change all back to 100% black (C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100), I changed the color on all the edits I made to 100% black but the old text is at C=75 M=68 Y=67 K=90.

I tried opening it on Illustrator and changed the appearance of black but nothing happened. I figured maybe the changes would be seen when I exported the files, but that was not the case. I exported the file and checked the black again, nothing happened.

I'm I missing a step here? I have been reading online but none of the forums help. I don't want to change to grayscale because the document also has colors in it. I attempted to change on Acrobat but that was a big fail as well.

is there any way I can change the black to 100%!? I really don't want to re-do the whole brochure, I am sure there is a way around this I just can't seem to figure it out.

here is one of the pages if you want to take a stab at it: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4ary3bldm3vtio/4_33.pdf?dl=0

Please HELP!

Comment: If you open the PDF in Illustrator do you have objects for the text (outlines or type, it doesn't matter) or do you just have a flattened image?

Comment: HI Cai! Flattened image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, well I would retype it cause you'll get much better results but if you really need to do it, here's what I came up with for you.

Go into your channels. Select any areas of composite black

[image]

and with CMYK channel (the top composite channel) checked, do Copy. Then go to the Black channel and do Paste.

Now reselect and go into the Cyan and fill with white, the Magenta and fill with white, and the Yellow and fill with White. Congrats, you're done.

[image]

Comment: I tried talking to him, btw he's in China, and he said the black needs to be 100% Black (C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100) beacuse if i do any other combination of that then the print will come out blurry as the process printing uses 4 plates that overlay to make the full colour spectrum. Although precise, the registration of the 4-plates will shift during the print process.

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez that's ridiculous and would imply he can't print the color green as an example. Text yes, images no, and the press should be properly calibrated to minimize, almost eliminate such registration issues. If you're not stuck with that printer, I'd find a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am. The only issue he sees in the file is the black. Since some of the text is so small he assures it will come out blurry. This was my initial reaction too. I have never heard of such thing! UGH!!!

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez wait what text? I didn't check every single letter but it looked like you had retyped the entire right side to be 100% K. For text, yes you should use 100% black but it looked to me like you did. What text is still in composite that is the concern?

Comment: Wow! I just realized I uploaded one fo the pages were i had edited all the text. I changed the link in the original post 
here is a better example:https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4ary3bldm3vtio/4_33.pdf?dl=0
Some of the text is at 100% black but other is not. Check it out!

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez updated my answer

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez Is the text all on a white background?

Comment: @Ryan - Wow! Thanks! I guess I'm going to have to go through all the pages and do this with all the font. Much faster than re-typing the whole document that's for sure! For the font that's not on white background I'm going to have to re-type.

Comment: @Cai  - Most of it, but not all.

Comment: it isn't *just* a registration problem: the colors are screened, usually 150-lpi or less which is a visible dot and have a dot appearance, whereas vector text can be outputted at the maximum resolution of the platemaker and will appear smooth. 8pt text will suffer from both.

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez for the text on a white background you can do as Ryan said, but the others will be harder and next to impossible if it is over an image for example. You should really be sending files with vector text (i.e not an image).

Comment: I got lucky! Most text is on top of a white background. What a mission! This would all have been avoided if i had the original design files.

Comment: @Yorik - can i even convert the flatten image to vector at this point?

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez you would need to redraw the file to have vectors. But the text would turn out a lot better if you spent the time to retype it all. This is a hacky solution at best. The above solution can also work with a small change for text on any solid colored background but again -- hacky at best.

Comment: @DanielaOrdonez: I don't think so, I was pointing out that your supplier is not entirely wrong and probably not merely unable to properly register "rich-black" text at small point sizes. Just filling in a small gap in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys! I guess I am going to need to re-type the whole file.

Comment: @Ryan, I know this question is old, but just for the record: Problems with registration isn't *just* a question of calibrating the equipment. It can be minimized but never completely eliminated because the paper changes in size when getting wet. It's worse with uncoated than coated paper.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that wherever you are working on this file you are working in the correct color space. Photoshop and Illustrator can both be finicky when it comes to converting colors when you aren't in the appropriate color space. On the tab with the file name you can find which color space you are working on it'll say something like "File.pdf @ 100% (RGB/GPU Preview)." If your file says RGB then your problem comes from illustrator taking that 100% black and changing it to RGB black. In Illustrator go to File > Document Mode > CMYK Color and in Photoshop go to Image > Mode > CMYK Color. Then change the color to 100% Black and export the PDF again.

Comment: Hi Miguel! The files in PSD are in CMYK and the text I did edit is at 100% Black (C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100) but the original text that was not edited is not 100% black, it's at C=75 M=68 Y=67 K=90. This text is not editable and I don't want to redo the whole file. How do I get to change the old text (non-editable "image") to 100% black?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change the color to 100% Black if you can no longer edit the text. Unfortunately with a flattened image trying to edit text means selecting all the pixels that make up the text and adding a new fill that is 100% black, but with that method you will get a lot of jagged edges and it might be faster to just recreate the file.

Comment: Another thing you might want to try is to add a white fill on top of just the sections with text, to cover it up, and retype everything. You'll be able to keep the rest of the design.

Answer (score 1):

I found a setting under Edit: Preferences: Appearance of Black: change output to display and output All blacks accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I know this forum is old, but I was having the same issue and resolved it by doing the following, hopefully, this will help someone else having the same issue?

Instead of clicking on the fill swatch where you can enter in the colour values, open up Swatches tab (under the window) and click on the + symbol for New Swatch, a values window will pop open, enter in the values on this pop-up window, and this should do the trick. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Its because You have to colorise to BlacK100 ungroupped EAN lines as outlines.

Comment: can [edit] to expand your explanation? It's difficult to understand what you're trying to say with just one line (also the sentence is confusing)